# Two components with the same id ‘{}’ can’t be added to the application. AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, calendarextender

I am aware that it is a well-known error. But the solutions available online are not working for me.

I have AJAX calendar extender inside an updatepanel. 
When I do postback, it is trying to create the AJAX extendar controls twice, hence the problem.

Solutions available are saying to set debug=false, which makes the error disappear but duplicate controls are created on the page. 
Each control is appearing twice.

What else I could try?

Thanks
ARB

Comment: My project is in .NET 4.0. So, I installed ajax 4.0 and no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it solved by moving controls into a separate update panel.

I had both GridView and Ajax extender controls in one update panel. The postback is happening when I clicked on gridview row.

Now I have GridView in one update panel and other controls in another update panel. That fixed it.

Hope it saves somebody's invaluable time

Answer (score 0):

If you have this tag in your content or masterpage

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
```

Add  `ScriptMode="Release"` in the above tag.